# Unity PropertyDrawer for Serializable object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I try to draw defualt inspector for serializable object **manually** , and **Here is my code**:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public int ID;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ItemGroup
{
    public Item item;
    public int count;
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Item item;
    public ItemGroup itemGroup;
    public Item[] items;
    public ItemGroup[] itemGroups;
}
```

The **default inspector** is look like this:

[image]

Then I add the `PropertyDrawer` script for `Item` and `ItemGroup`

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Item))]
public class ItemDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property, label);
    }
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var style = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.foldoutHeader);
        style.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;
        
        if (property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup(position, property.isExpanded, label, style))
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
            position.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            position.y += position.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property.FindPropertyRelative("Name"));
            position.y += position.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property.FindPropertyRelative("ID"));
            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndFoldoutHeaderGroup();
    }
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ItemGroup))]
public class ItemGroupDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property, label);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var style = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.foldoutHeader);
        style.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;
        var itemProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("item");
        var countProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("count");

        position.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        if (property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup(position, property.isExpanded, label, style))
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
            position.y += position.height;
            position.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(itemProperty);
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, itemProperty, true);
            position.y += position.height;
            position.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, countProperty);
            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndFoldoutHeaderGroup();
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** When **Enable** `ItemDrawer` and **Disable** `ItemGroupDrawer`, the indent of `Item` field is wrong, see below.How to make it correct both in `ItemGroup` class and Array?

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Item))] //Enable ItemDrawer
//[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ItemGroup))] //Disable ItemGroupDrawer
```

[image]

**Question 2**: When enable both `ItemDrawer` and `ItemGroupDrawer`, there is a error:

but the **default inspector** it did has foldout header

**So how to use `PropertyDrawer` to draw `Item` and `ItemGroup`'s properties manually that make it look like default inspector?**

I don't want to use `EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property);`

I want to draw their properties one by one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The indent is wrong since you pass in the original `position` without any indentation .. the `EditorGUI.indentLevel` only directly affects the property fields drawn without a rect bit via `EditorGUILayout`.

You can get an indented rect however by using

```
var indentedRect = EditorGUI.IndentedRect(position);
```

However, until now I don't see a real purpose in having a custom drawer for your types .. what's wrong with the default drawer? ;)

Comment: actually I want to use the properties in first class(`Item`) to clamp `ItemGroup.Count`

Answer (score 0):

thanks derHugo, I have solved it

**Answer 1**: I should add `position = EditorGUI.IndentedRect(position);` to the top of `OnGUI`

**Answer 2**: I should use `EditorGUI.Foldout` rather than `EditorGUI.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup`